# Pasting Formula from an Array in VBA into an excel table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

So I am trying to make a VBA scripts that changes all indirect formula in a selection into direct reference, aim is to improve performance of my excel workbook. Below is the code:

```
Call manual
Dim continue As Integer
continue = MsgBox("This cannot be undone.  Continue anyway?", vbOKCancel)
If continue <> vbOK Then Exit Sub

Dim formula_array() As Variant

row_cnt = Selection.Rows.count
col_cnt = Selection.Columns.count

ReDim formula_array(1 To row_cnt, 1 To col_cnt)

If row_cnt = 1 And col_cnt = 1 Then
    formula_array(1, 1) = Selection.formula
Else
    formula_array = Selection.formula
End If
'for some reason formula_array = Selection.formula gives an error when I select only one cell
count = 0
Dim i As Integer, y As Integer
For i = 1 To row_cnt
    For y = 1 To col_cnt
        frmula = formula_array(i, y)
        oldfunc = find_full_formula(frmula, "indirect(")
        Do While (oldfunc <> "")
            newfunc = Application.Evaluate(oldfunc)
            If IsError(newfunc) Then
                newfunc = ""
            End If
            oldfunc = "indirect(" & oldfunc & ")"
            formula_array(i, y) = Replace(formula_array(i, y), oldfunc, newfunc, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
            frmula = formula_array(i, y)
            oldfunc = find_full_formula(frmula, "indirect(")
            count = count + 1
        Loop
    Next y
Next i
Dim temp As String
Selection.formula = formula_array
MsgBox count
Call auto
```

Here the find_full_formula function gives arguments of any function, input is the start of that function and the whole formula. So if you have a formula"Indirect("A1:B2")" then the result of this function would be "A1:B2".

The whole script works very well for normal ranges except when I try to run in on a column of an excel table where the selection also includes the first cell of the column (first cell of data, so not the header) then the result is that all cells in that column have the same formula as the first cell. What is also interesting is that if I select all cells of a column of the table except the first one then the result is fine but only when the first cell is also involved then the problem arises. It obviously looks like some auto-fill feature but I have turned off all such settings that I could find and still this issue isn't solved.

okay, I am adding below a much simpler version of VBA code to highlight my problem:

```
Dim arr(1 To 4, 1 To 1) As Variant
arr(1, 1) = "2+2"
arr(2, 1) = "=3+2"
arr(3, 1) = "=4+2"
arr(4, 1) = "=5+2"
Range("A2:A5").Formula = arr
```

this code above works just fine, however the one below results in "=2+2" as formula for each cell of my table.

```
Dim arr(1 To 4, 1 To 1) As Variant
arr(1, 1) = "=2+2"
arr(2, 1) = "=3+2"
arr(3, 1) = "=4+2"
arr(4, 1) = "=5+2"
Range("A2:A5").Formula = arr
```

Table in excel looks something like this:
[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltHzL.png)

Comment: Does the issue only raise if you select the whole data range of that column in your table (ListObject), or does it also appear if only eg the first cells are selected? Does it also appear if you select the first cell of that column's data range (+ somme more) *and* at least one cell *outside* the table (eg. selection continues below the table)? I would need to write my own code to reproduce - can't use yours because too many routines missing. Maybe you want to provide a more generalized version that only shows how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have to try selecting just the first cell to see what happens but what I think is that this issue won't happen if I just run it on the first cell, the rest will be unaffected. I did running it on the whole column but making a tweak in the code such that the first cell is left blank and only filled at the end of the script just separately after the whole array is pasted, then this issue didn't happen. I will post a more generic code without missing routines tomorrow when I get back to work.

Comment: Also this has to do something with pasting formulas, if I just paste values then I don't have this problem.

Comment: I have added two simpler pieces of code in the end of my post which shows the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce this: the second code sets the formula of the whole column of the table (ListObject), just like entering a formula manually and thus triggering the AutoFill feature for formulas in tables. Interestingly Excel uses only the first formula provided. Maybe you need to code an exception for the special case "selection intersects ListObject / first cell of ListObject". I'll check this out later and provide you some code if I find a general solution on this.

Comment: I have that sort of a workaround but then if I am pasting this array on a table with multiple columns then it still is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works in all cases I checked out, but it's not beautiful - consider it as a workaround:

1. set `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False`
2. set formula to cells by looping them (one by one)

None of these alone sets the formulas as expected if selection matches a `ListObject.DataBodyRange`.

```
Sub Test()
    ' select a range that fits
    ' the following arrays dimensions

    Dim arr(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Variant
    arr(1, 1) = "=2+2": arr(1, 2) = "=12+2"
    arr(2, 1) = "=3+2": arr(2, 2) = "=13+2"
    arr(3, 1) = "=4+2": arr(3, 2) = "=14+2"
    arr(4, 1) = "=5+2": arr(4, 2) = "=15+2"

    ' deactivate AutoFillFormulasInLists; store setting to restore
    Dim bAutoFill As Boolean
    bAutoFill = Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False

    Selection.ClearContents

    ' `Selection.FormulaR1C1 = arr` does NOT work in case of
    ' Selection = ListObject.DataBodyRange
    ' => loop cells (slower and more lines of code)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            Selection(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = arr(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = bAutoFill
End Sub
```

Hopefully somebody else will paste a more straightforward solution!

Comment: This will work for sure but unfortunately it is much slower, which matters when thousands of cells are involved which is the case in my project. I had it like this only initially and due to performance issues of the script I moved it to storing in array and copying it all at once. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: In that case I would go with an exception just for the case you have to handle an *entire column* of a list object (for me that's the *only* case that does not work as expected). Or is that your standard case? Then maybe you work around by handling the first or the last row separately. Maybe you should nail down your question and ask more precise to attract a more experienced user (something like "how to set all cells of Table (ListObject) column to different formulas by setting Range = Array in VBA").

Answer (score 0):

Here is another much more simple solution that seems to work for me: simply explicitly dimension your one-dimensional arrays as two-dimensional arrays.  So instead of Dim V(1 to 10) use Dim V(1 to 10, 1 to 1).  Although this second variant array is technically a 2-d array, it is a trivial case because the second dimension is only 1 deep - and so it's really still just a 1-d array.  Nonetheless if you then perform the operation of assigning this trivial 2-d array to a range in Excel it seems to work and not duplicate the first value via auto-fill.